# Using a Variable Out of Scope of a Callback Function in Node.js / Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using a library called node-geocoder in express js which has the following code:

```
var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

var options = {
  provider: 'google',

  // Optional depending on the providers
  httpAdapter: 'https', // Default
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY', // for Mapquest, OpenCage, Google Premier
  formatter: null         // 'gpx', 'string', ...
};

var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);

// Using callback
geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris', function(err, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

The response variable(res) in the geocode method's callback function holds an object with location properties such as latitutde and longitude.  The link for this package is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-geocoder)

I was wondering if there was a way to use that response variable outside of the callback function in the geocode method.  I need to pull the latitude and longitude properties and I don't want to keep the rest of the code within that callback function.

As a noob I tried just returning the object and storing it in a variable like so:

```
var object = geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris', function(err, res) {

   return res;

});
```

This doesn't work since it's in the callback and not returned in the actual geocode method.

Comment: One way to solve it is to call a function from the callback. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but there are a couple of options to get closer to that.

One would be to have your callback be a defined function and use that as the callback:

```
const doSomething = (err, res) => { /* do something */ }

geocoder.geocode('abc', doSomething);
```

Not really much different, but can make it a little cleaner.

You can also "promisify" the function to have it return a `Promise`. Something like this would do the trick:

```
const geocodePromise = (path) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    geocoder.geocode(path, (err, res) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(res));
});

geocodePromise('abc')
  .then(res => { /* do something */ })
  .catch(err => { /* do something */ });
```

Finally, if you are using Babel for transpiling (or Node version 7.6.0 or higher, which has it natively), you can use `async` and `await`. Using the same promisified version of the function as above, you'd have to wrap your main code in an `async` function. I generally use a self-calling anonymous function for that:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await geocodePromise(path);

    /* do something with res */
  } catch (err) {
    /* do something with err */
  }
})();
```

With this, you get the closest to what you want, but you'll still have to wrap your main code up in a function because you can't `await` at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the response of your function outside the callback by calling another function.

```
geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris', function(err, res) {
  if(!err){
    // call a function if there is no error
    console.log(res);
    myFunction();
  }
 });

function myFunction(){
 //do your processing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to keep the rest of the code within that callback function.

The code doesn't have to be *in* the callback, it just has to be called *from* the callback.

So you write your function (or functions) as normal:

```
function handleInfo(info) {
    doSomethingWithInfo(info);
    doSomethignElse(info);
    // ...
}
// ...
```

...and then call those functions when you have the data:

```
geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris', function(err, info) {
  if (err) {
      // Handle error
  } else {
      handleInfo(info);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`geocode` can return promise already, no need to re-wrap it. If you don't care about the error and just want to grab the response's location data. You can do this

```
var locationData = geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris').then( function(res){
    return res;
});
```